Keeping a "pointer" to the of the "parent array" from which a "derived array" was produced?
(Aside: my question is equally applicable to numpy structured arrays and non-structured arrays.)
Suppose I have a numpy structured array with the dtype:
EXAMPLE_DTYPE = np.dtype([("alpha", np.str_), ("beta", np.int64)])

I have a wrapper around the numpy data array of this dtype, and then I want to implement a special __getitem__ for it:
class ExampleArray:
  data: np.ndarray = np.array([("hello", 0), ("world", 1)], dtype=EXAMPLE_DTYPE)

  def __getitem__(self, index: int|str) -> SpecializedArray:
    return SpecializedArray(index, self.data[index])

SpecializedArray is a class which keeps track of the indices used to specialize from a parent array into a derived array:
class SpecializedArray:
  specialization: int|str 
  data: np.ndarray

  def __init__(self, specialization: int|str, data: np.ndarray) -> None:
    self.specialization = specialization
    self.data = data

  def __repr__(self) -> str:
    return f"{self.specialization} -> {self.data}"

I would like SpecializedArray to ideally have a "reference" to the parent array it was derived from. What is the best way to provide such a reference? Should I provide the parent by slicing it, since slicing creates a view?
# method in ExampleArray
  def __getitem__(self, index: int|str) -> SpecializedArray:
    # suppose that SpecializedArray took the parent as a third argument
    return SpecializedArray(index, self.data[index], self.data[:])


Why not just self.data? Why the slice?

@user2357112 I'm not sure whether a copy will unnecessarily be made, while the slicing forces a view to be created?

It won't create a copy. Even if Python did work in a way where that would create a copy, making a view wouldn't help - those same (nonexistent) mechanics would just copy the view.

@user2357112 I guess I am never sure when Python just passes a reference to an object, versus creating a deepcopy.

Python almost never copies anything you don't explicitly copy.

@user2357112 sure, but that reinforces my point: I am never sure when it will, and when it won't. What are the rules? How do I control it explicitly?

If the docs don't say something makes a copy, it probably doesn't make a copy.

Python reference, copy, and deepcopy is one thing.  Numpy view versus copy is another.  If it's a view it's base will be the array it was derived from (via reshape, basic indexing etc).  If the base is None`, the array is a copy or other wise 'original'.
